# JTable is not returning data for all records

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am using a `JTable` and selecting all the rows by CTRL+A.
I am getting the selected rows correct but when I am trying to get the values it only gives the values from viewport.

I am adding a part of my code here.

```
JTable _resultTable = new JTable();
JScrollPane _resultPane = new JScrollPane();

_resultTable.setModel(JUTableBindingFactory.createAttributeListBinding(_panelBinding, _resultTable , _searchViewName, _searchViewName + "Iter", _searchViewName + "IterBinding", FIELDS));
_resultPane.getViewport().add(_resultTable);
MultiSelectionListListener.setMultiSelectionModel(_resultTable);

_changeSelectedButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
    int[] tableRows = _resultTable.getSelectedRows();

    System.out.println(" length :" + tableRows.length);

    Row[] dataRows = new Row[tableRows.length];

    RowIterator iterator = null;
    JUIteratorBinding iterBinding = _panelBinding.getRowIterBinding(_searchViewName, _searchViewName + "Iter",_searchViewName.replace('.','_')+"IterBinding");
    iterator = iterBinding != null ? iterBinding.getNavigatableRowIterator() : null;

    for (int i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++)
    {
      dataRows[i] = iterator.getRowAtRangeIndex(rowIndexToRangeIndex(tableRows[i], iterator));
      System.out.println(" Name :" + i + " " +dataRows[i].getAttribute(1));
    }
  }
```

From above code snippet if the number of records present are 50 and we can see 10 records, then the output is somehow :

length :50

Name: 0 Nadine

Name : 1 Nadine1

Name : 2 Nadine23

Name : 3 Nadine3

Name : 4 Nadine4

Name : 5 Nadine5

Name : 6 Nadine6

Name : 7 Nadine7

Name : 8 Nadine8

Name : 9 Nadine9

Name : 10 Nadine10

And after printing 10 records it gives `NullPointerExpetion` at `dataRows[i].getAttribute(1)` .

So that means it is not picking the data for the records that are not on the viewport.

So what could be the solution ?

**EDIT**
I am using BC4J binding to get the data in the table.

Comment: 1. resultPane != _resultPane, 2. your Bindings factory is broken (can't found nicer words) 3. this question probably haven't something to do with Swing, JTable. 4. for better help sooner post an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for Bindings factory passed as data  source for XxxTableModel

Comment: may be it has to do something with Model, but I cannot post the whole code here.

Comment: nobody asked you to _post the whole code_ Google SSCCE if you don't know what it is. Seeing you use some binding framework, better add that as tag - that might attract experts in the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have searched the issue on internet and found a [link](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/617322) which helps me to understand the issue.
The data was not being loaded because the binding loads that much data which needs to be shown on the viewport. So while trying to access the data which was not on viewport was giving error.

To solve the issue we just need to load all the data in View Object by tweaking the bindings a bit.

From

```
 JUIteratorBinding iterBinding = _panelBinding.getRowIterBinding(_searchViewName, _searchViewName + "Iter",_searchViewName.replace('.','_')+"IterBinding");
```

To

```
DCIteratorBinding iterBinding = _panelBinding.getIteratorBinding(_searchViewName, _searchViewName + "Iter",_searchViewName.replace('.','_')+"IterBinding", -1);
```

The last argument `-1` is used to setRangeSize(-1), which will load all data.

Answer (score 2):

Some things suggested by your snippet:

- Don't mix model and view coordinates, [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) them as required.
- Access your `TableModel`, not the data structure that was used to construct it.